# KeyError while using mt.reg (econtools)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-error

I'm using mt.reg to compute Conley standard errors but get this error: KeyError: 'id'
I'm doing this simple regression

```
shac_params = {
    'x': 'lon', 
    'y': 'lat',   
    'kern': 'tria',     
    'band': 0.0025,          
}

results = mt.reg(data, 'y', 'x',
                            fe_name='id',
                            shac=shac_params
                        )
```

Both y and x are float variables, 'id' is a numerical id for unit. **All of these variables are in the dataframe.**
I've tried changing it from float to string, but the same error appears.

This is the full error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
CodeFile.ipynb Cell 167 in 7
      1 shac_params = {
      2     'x': 'lon',   # Column in `df`
      3     'y': 'lat',    # Column in `df`
      4     'kern': 'tria',     # Kernel name
      5     'band': 0.0025,          # Kernel bandwidth, it's in coordinates
      6 }
----> 7 results = mt.reg(data, 'y', 'x',
      8                             fe_name='id',
      9                             shac=shac_params
     10                         )

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\econtools\metrics\api.py:82, in reg(df, y_name, x_name, fe_name, a_name, nosingles, vce_type, cluster, shac, addcons, nocons, awt_name, save_mem, check_colinear)
     71 fe_name = _a_name_deprecation_handling(a_name, fe_name)
     73 RegWorker = Regression(
     74     df, y_name, x_name,
     75     fe_name=fe_name, nosingles=nosingles, addcons=addcons, nocons=nocons,
   (...)
     79     check_colinear=check_colinear,
     80 )
---> 82 results = RegWorker.main()
     83 return results

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\econtools\metrics\core.py:49, in RegBase.main(self)
     48 def main(self):
---> 49     self.set_sample()
     50     self.estimate()
     51     self.get_vce()

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\econtools\metrics\core.py:77, in RegBase.set_sample(self)
     75 # Demean or add constant
     76 if self.fe_name is not None:
---> 77     self._demean_sample()
     78 elif self.addcons:
     79     _cons = np.ones(self.y.shape[0])

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\econtools\metrics\core.py:94, in RegBase._demean_sample(self)
     92 self.y_raw = self.y.copy()
     93 for var in self.vars_in_reg:
---> 94     self.__dict__[var] = _demean(self.A, self.__dict__[var])

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\econtools\metrics\core.py:252, in _demean(A, df)
    250 group_name = A.name
    251 mean = df.groupby(A).mean()
--> 252 large_mean = force_df(A).join(mean, on=group_name).drop(group_name,
    253                                                         axis=1)
    254 if df.ndim == 1:
    255     large_mean = large_mean.squeeze()

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9729, in DataFrame.join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort, validate)
   9566 def join(
   9567     self,
   9568     other: DataFrame | Series | Iterable[DataFrame | Series],
   (...)
   9574     validate: str | None = None,
   9575 ) -> DataFrame:
   9576     """
   9577     Join columns of another DataFrame.
   9578 
   (...)
   9727     5  K1  A5   B1
   9728     """
-> 9729     return self._join_compat(
   9730         other,
   9731         on=on,
   9732         how=how,
   9733         lsuffix=lsuffix,
   9734         rsuffix=rsuffix,
   9735         sort=sort,
   9736         validate=validate,
   9737     )

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9768, in DataFrame._join_compat(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort, validate)
   9758     if how == "cross":
   9759         return merge(
   9760             self,
   9761             other,
   (...)
   9766             validate=validate,
   9767         )
-> 9768     return merge(
   9769         self,
   9770         other,
   9771         left_on=on,
   9772         how=how,
   9773         left_index=on is None,
   9774         right_index=True,
   9775         suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix),
   9776         sort=sort,
   9777         validate=validate,
   9778     )
   9779 else:
   9780     if on is not None:

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:148, in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    131 @Substitution("\nleft : DataFrame or named Series")
    132 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=0)
    133 def merge(
   (...)
    146     validate: str | None = None,
    147 ) -> DataFrame:
--> 148     op = _MergeOperation(
    149         left,
    150         right,
    151         how=how,
    152         on=on,
    153         left_on=left_on,
    154         right_on=right_on,
    155         left_index=left_index,
    156         right_index=right_index,
    157         sort=sort,
    158         suffixes=suffixes,
    159         indicator=indicator,
    160         validate=validate,
    161     )
    162     return op.get_result(copy=copy)

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:737, in _MergeOperation.__init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, indicator, validate)
    730 self._cross = cross_col
    732 # note this function has side effects
    733 (
    734     self.left_join_keys,
    735     self.right_join_keys,
    736     self.join_names,
--> 737 ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    739 # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
    740 # to avoid incompatible dtypes
    741 self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:1237, in _MergeOperation._get_merge_keys(self)
   1233     else:
   1234         # Then we're either Hashable or a wrong-length arraylike,
   1235         #  the latter of which will raise
   1236         k = cast(Hashable, k)
-> 1237         left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(k))
   1238         join_names.append(k)
   1239 if isinstance(self.right.index, MultiIndex):

File c:\Users\Anaconda3\eny\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:1778, in NDFrame._get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1776     values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1777 else:
-> 1778     raise KeyError(key)
   1780 # Check for duplicates
   1781 if values.ndim > 1:

KeyError: 'id'
```

Comment: That just says your dataframe does not contain a column called `id`.  Is that true?

Comment: It does contain that column that's why I do not understand why this is happening.